# gcc 共有ライブラリへの静的ライブラリリンク

Tags: gcc

共有ライブラリ（`*.so`）に対して、
アーカイブ（`*.a`）を静的リンクしたいのですが
色々とトライしたものの、実現が出来ていません。

そもそも、上記シチュエーション自体が
イレギュラーだと認識していますが、
linuxないしgccの特性上、実現不可能なのでしょうか。

Comment: トライしたコマンドラインを提示するとアドバイスが得られると思います。

Comment: プラットフォーム (Linux/Windows/その他) とかもあったほうがよりコメントつきやすくなるでしょうね。っていうか XY 問題？なぜそんなことをしたいのか、解決したい真の問題を書くと代替案が出ることもあります。

Comment: -staticフラグはすでにお試しですよね？通常ご利用の共有ライブラリ.soが静的ライブラリ.aも提供していなければできません。使ったことはないのですが、ラッパーもあるみたいですよ。どこまでポータブルなバイナリになるのか不明ですが。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725472/static-link-of-shared-library-function-in-gcc